# Not able to customize Firebase Dynamic Link App preview

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

does anyone have experience in customising app preview page that Firebase Dynamic Links are opening before app or Appstore is open.

I am familiar with customising all social metadata properties, but how do you change "OPEN" label on the CTA button, and "Save my place in the app..." text - it always come in english no matter what device language or app default language is.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?